# Convert Concentration (particles/ml) to (mg/ml)

Tags: everyday-chemistry, concentration

I am struggling with converting concentration from (particles/ml) to (mg/ml). I have the concentration for latex particle (particles/ml) and I want to convert it to (mg/ml).

I worked  out the number of moles since I know the the pressure and volume. But I am not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 1):

First lets see how to get from particles $N$ per volume to mass $m$ per volume.

Dividing the particle number by the Avogadro constant gives moles.

$$
\frac{N}{V}\cdot \frac{1}{N_\mathrm A}=\frac{n}{V}
$$

Multiplying moles with molar mass gives mass.
$$
\frac{n}{V}\cdot M=\frac{m}{V}
$$
Concluding:
$$
\frac{N}{V}\cdot \frac{M}{N_\mathrm A}=\frac{m}{V}
$$

Now your problem arises because you do not know the molar mass. Because you probably have some distribution function of particle size and not just one size. I just assume now that you made an emulsion polymerization in order to get the latex particles or bought them commercially. Then this distribution is very sharp and you can easily take the averaged molar mass as the molar mass of the most probable particle size.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think pressure matters here but if you know the molar concentration you can work out how many g/L which is the same numerically as mg/ml